How to find the right ami id for amazon linux 2
I have only found it so far by chat gpt, but not by googling or by using the proposed way from aws:
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon

nor is the AMI shown in the EC2 console the correct one.
What is the correct way to find the AMI ID for the region in cloudformation?

This might help: Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog

I could find by simple going to ec2 and "create an instance". I was taking the ARM one with t2.micro, which would not work.
